# Extending the Session Middleware

Tags: python, django, session, storage, middleware

I'm using Django 1.3, and I'd like to modify the session middleware to add some methods that will help me out.

**In ./settings.py**

```
SESSION_ENGINE='tcore.my_sessions.MySessionStore'
```

**In ./tcore/my_sessions.py:**

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.conf import settings

class MySessionStore(SessionStore):    
    ....
    def my custom methods here
```

However, I keep getting some weird exceptions when I do this. What's the proper way to make a custom Session Engine?

```
AttributeError at /create/
type object 'MySessionStore' has no attribute 'SessionStore'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/create/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'MySessionStore' has no attribute 'SessionStore'

Python Version: 2.6.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation of SESSION_ENGINE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-SESSION_ENGINE), take such an example: `django.contrib.sessions.backends.file`. The source of this module defines a SessionStore class. So that's what you should do too:

./tcore/my_sessions.py:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DbSessionStore

class SessionStore(DbSessionStore):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'hello from SessionStore'
        super(SessionStore, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

settings.py:

```
SESSION_ENGINE='tcore.my_sessions'
```

Comment: Thanks jpic.  I'll give that a try and let you know how it works out.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: To further comment, it seems as though I was providing the path to the  actual SessionStore class when I needed to provide the path to the module containing that class.  Thank you for clarifying that.