# Extending database-backed session engines

Tags: python, django, session

I plan to extend the default sessionstore by adding an account_id, for this I followed this link [extending-database-backed-session-engines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#extending-database-backed-session-engines), but the account_id is not being created on migrate.

The application is located in `app` folder.

In **./settings.py**. I have:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
)
```

According to this link [Extending the Session Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578204/extending-the-session-middleware) I have:

```
SESSION_ENGINE='app.sessions'
```

In **./sessions.py**. I have:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
from django.contrib.sessions.base_session import AbstractBaseSession

from django.db import models


class SessionStore(DBStore):
    @classmethod
    def get_model_class(cls):
        return CustomSession

    def create_model_instance(self, data):
        obj = super(SessionStore, self).create_model_instance(data)
        try:
            account_id = int(data.get('_auth_user_id'))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            account_id = None
        obj.account_id = account_id
        return obj


class CustomSession(AbstractBaseSession):
    account_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'sessions'

    @classmethod
    def get_session_store_class(cls):
        return SessionStore
```

**Edit:** With this configuration the sessions table is not created.

I also tried to to add the `sessions.py` file in a `sessions` module, and to add `app.sessions` to the `installed_apps` section in `settings`, the same result.

Do I also need to modify the migrations file to create the Session table ?

## SOLUTION

I've solved the issue. The solution is:

1. Change `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` as follows:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'app'
   ]
   ```
2. Change `SESSION_ENGINE` in `settings.py as follows:

   ```
   SESSION_ENGINE='app.sessions'
   ```
3. In `./app/sessions.py`, I have:

   ```
   from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
   import app

   class SessionStore(DBStore):
       @classmethod
       def get_model_class(cls):
           return app.models.models.CustomSession

       def create_model_instance(self, data):
           obj = super(SessionStore, self).create_model_instance(data)
           try:
               user_id = int(data.get('_auth_user_id'))
           except (ValueError, TypeError):
               user_id = None
           obj.user_id = user_id
           return obj
   ```
4. In `./app/models/models.py`, I have

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   from django.contrib.sessions.base_session import AbstractBaseSession
   from django.db import models

   from app.mysessions import SessionStore


   class CustomSession(AbstractBaseSession):
       user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_index=True)

       class Meta:
           app_label = 'app'

       @classmethod
       def get_session_store_class(cls):
           return SessionStore
   ```
5. Regular makemigrations and migrate. And all should be running.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an app with a custom session model, you should include this in your `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of `django.contrib.sessions`.

Having

```
SESSION_ENGINE='app.sessions'
```

looks wrong to me. `SESSION_ENGINE` should be the path to your `AbstractBaseSession` subclass.

Comment: Do I include app.sessions instead of django.contrib.sessions in the INSTALLED_APPS section ?

Comment: Yes, if your app is located at `app.sessions`.